# Como convertir la hora en decimal en php

Tags: php, php7, php5

Hola alguien me puede ayudar como convertir la hora en un decimal ejemplo tengo una función que saca la diferencia de dos horas con diff y después la convierto en hora y minutos con format pero ahora quiero es que aparezcan en decimal que sea asi extraNocturnaEntrada='1.45', dejo código de lo que tengo hasta ahora

```
$Date_MovimientoEntrada='07:00:00';
$Date_FinNocheLaboral=''08:45:00;
  $extraNocturnaEntrada =  $Date_MovimientoEntrada->diff($Date_FinNocheLaboral);
  $extraNocturnaEntrada =  $extraNocturnaEntrada->format('%H:%I');
```

Answer (score 0):

`diff()` te devuelve un objeto del tipo `DateInterval`. Si lees el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/dateinterval.format.php), verás que para formatear horas sin ceros en los objetos de tipo `DateInterval`, debes usar `h`.

Así debería funcionar (usaré variables más cortas, no es necesario declarar variables kilométricas):

```
$dateBegin=new DateTime('07:00:00');
$dateEnd=new DateTime('08:45:00');
$dateDiff=$dateBegin->diff($dateEnd);
echo $dateDiff->format('%h.%I');
```

**Salida:**

```
1.45
```